# How to implement DllMain entry point in Go

Tags: python, windows, go, dll, dllmain

I'm using Go to build a DLL.

I'm not able to implement windows [DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain).

My goal is when an app loads the dll via [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) to call the `Test` method, the `DllMain` will be called as well. However currently the app is kind of stuck in deadlock and nothing happens.

The app is quite simple python code

```py
# App code
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL("./mydll.dll")
lib.Test()
```

Notes:

- I am building using

  ```
  go version go1.16.4 windows/amd64
  ```

  and building using

  ```
  go build -o mydll.dll --buildmode=c-shared
  ```
- If I remove `DllMain`, everything works fine and app can call the `Test` method successfully.
- I'm aware that I can `switch` case under `DllMain` to specify conditions such as process attached, detached ...etc, I just wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

```golang
//Go Code
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

//export Test
func Test() {
    os.Create("fooFile")
}


//export DllMain
func DllMain(a uintptr, b uint32, c uintptr) int32 {
    return 1
}

func main() {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DllMain` can't be a Go function, since invoking a Go function the first time initializes the **Go runtime**, which can't be done in scope of `DllMain` (there are [*very* few things](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices#general-best-practices) that can be done in scope of `DllMain`).

As a workaround, you can write `DllMain` in C and invoke Go code in a **separate thread** as in [this example](https://gist.github.com/NaniteFactory/7a82b68e822b7d2de44037d6e7511734). But you can't synchronize with that thread in the scope of `DllMain`, doing so will again lead to a deadlock.

There's also [`_cgo_wait_runtime_init_done`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/cgo/libcgo.h#L59), but it also is asynchronous.

So if you need to perform some Go action synchronously on DLL attachment, you're out of luck. It's best to just define an "`Init`" exported function and call it before calling any other API.

And of course, the idiomatic way in Go to initialize on load is via an [`init()` function](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/the-go-init-function/):

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("init()")
}

//export Test
func Test() {
    fmt.Println("Test()")
}

func main() {
}
```

Compile and run:

```
go build -o mydll.dll --buildmode=c-shared
rundll32 mydll,Test
```

Output:

```
init()
Test()
```